# PHP update mysqli only works until closing browser

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-update

I have a question about the update function in mysqli.
For school, I'm trying to create a click counter for my website which counts how many times a user has visited a certain page.

So far I've come up with this:

```
<?php

    /*
     * ToDo: Check why number of clicks goes back to two when completely 
     * refreshing page.
     * 
     */

    include("init.php");
    session_start();

    //Count variable
    $clicks = 0;

    //Query for checking if there are any entry's in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `beoordelingen`.`clickcounter` WHERE `game_id`={$id}";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    //If query returns false
    if (!mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        //Create entry in database
        $insert = "INSERT INTO `beoordelingen`.`clickcounter` (`ID`, `game_id`, `clicks`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');";
        $createEntry = $conn->query($insert);
    }

    //If query returns true
    else {

        //Setting the number of clicks equal to $clicks
        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $clicks = $data['clicks'];
        }


        //Insert new number into database
        $sql="insert into `clickcounter` set `clicks`='{$clicks}', `game_id`='{$id}'
        on duplicate key update
        `clicks`=`clicks`+1;";
        $insertInto = $conn->query($sql);

        //Echo current number of clicks
        echo $clicks; 

    }

?>
```

The actual problem is that my update statement doesn't seem to work properly. If anyone would be able to spot why it doesn't work I'd be very happy.

The database is as following;

```
Beoordelingen <- Database
clickcounter <- Table which has the following three columns:
1. ID
2. game_id
3. clicks
```

The scripts does add an entry into  the databse with click count 2. So when I reload the page it says 2. And when refreshing it counts up, but doesn't update the table.

Thanks! If anything is unclear please ask me!

Comment: could you not simply try `UPDATE beoordelingen.clickcounter SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE clickcounter.game_id={$id}`?

Comment: You do not need to query twice on the same table. You can use the result from the first query itself.

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse.. I didn't see that one. Thanks Sohaib!

I'll give that a go RamRaider.

Comment: If it does count up on refreshing the table it means the database is getting updated cause that is where the click variable gets updated from. Maybe you are not refreshing or something. Secondly @RamRaider's suggestion is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to do all of it in one query if `game_id` is unique.

Given the following table structure the sql query below will insert if the relevant record does not exists and then update if it does.

---

```
create table `clickcounter` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `game_id` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    `clicks` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`),
    unique index `game_id` (`game_id`)
)
engine=innodb;
```

---

The trick is setting the `indices` on your table correctly ~ initially you don't know the value of the `ID` and I would guess that is an `auto increment primary key`? So, set a unique key on `game_id`...I hope it helps!

```
/* Could even change `clicks`='{$clicks}' to `clicks`=1 in initial insert */
$sql="insert into `clickcounter` set `clicks`='{$clicks}', `game_id`='{$id}'
        on duplicate key update
        `clicks`=`clicks`+1;";



<?php
    include("init.php");
    session_start();

    /* Where / how is "$id" defined? */


    /* insert new record / update existing */
    $sql="insert into `clickcounter` set `clicks`=1, `game_id`='{$id}'
            on duplicate key update
            `clicks`=`clicks`+1;";
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );


    /* retrieve the number of clicks */
    $sql="select `clicks` from `clickcounter` where `game_id`='{$id}';";
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );

    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) $clicks=intval( $rs->clicks );

    echo 'Total clicks: '.$clicks;
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'll post the updated code so you can check if I did it correctly.

Comment: Updated the code above. All it does is create multiple entrys in the DB when refreshing the page with game id 1 and click 1.

Comment: $id is defined in the init.php. It receives its ID from the url ...?id=1. This value is unique for every item on the website so game_id is equal to this unique number.

Comment: As a test I just created a simple script with exactly the same php as above, except for the included file and I hard-coded a value for $id - it ran perfectly and updated the db as expected ( initial insert then update on subsequent loads ). Has the `game_id` been set as a unique key in the db table `clickcounter` as suggested?

Comment: I was too quick saying it didn't work, because it works perfectly! :) Couldn't have done it better. Could you maybe explain to me what you did here? "while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) $clicks=intval( $rs->clicks );"

Comment: Sure - that is the equivalent of your `while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $clicks = $data['clicks'];
}` ~ but I find it easier to use `fetch_object` rather than `fetch_assoc` as it allows you to access fields like `$row->field` rather than `$row['field']`